# Как развернуть приложение во внутреннем каталоге?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Есть такое приложение https://github.com/maks1mp/video-chat-webrtc
Успешно разворачиваю его в корне, но не совсем понимаю как правильно развернуть его во внутреннем каталоге. (Пример: /var/www/html/**chat**/)
Где и какие пути нужно поменять?
Нужно ли менять конфиг nginx?

Comment: А чем ты его собираешь? У creatye-react-app в шаблонах используется `%PUBLIC_URL%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить конфиг nginx

```
location /chat/ {
    rewrite /chat/(.*) /$1  break;
}
```

В package.json добавить параметр
`"homepage": "/chat/"`

В index.html добавить `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">`

В App.js заменить `<BrowserRouter>` на `<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`

После чего заново скомпилировать и проверить.